# why $T=0 $ in $l^2$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion in  Functional analysis- Kreyszig book

In the book it is written that

> In the   space $l^2 $  we consider a  sequenec$(T_n)$ , where  $T_n: l^2 \to l^2$ is defined by
> $T_nx=(0,0,0,....0, e_{n+1},e_{n+2},.....) $
> Here  , $x=(e_1,e_2,....) \in l^2$.This operator  $T_n$ is linear and bounded , clearly $(T_n)$  is strongly operator   convergent to $0$  since $T_nx \to 0=0x$

My confusion : why $T=0 $?

**My thinking** : $$Tx=\lim_{n\to \infty}T_nx= \lim_{n\to \infty}(0,0,0,.....,e_{n+1},e_{n+2},....)$$

$$=(0,0,0,.....,e_{\infty},e_{\infty},....) \neq0$$

Here Im not getting   why  $T\equiv 0?$

Comment: What are your elements $e_\infty$ supposed to be?  Any element of $\ell^2$ is indexed by $\mathbb N$ and so is a (possibly very large but still) finite number, which is eventually zeroed by $T_n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ large enough.

Comment: Not quite 0'd, since you can have an element of $l^2$ with infinite non-zeros,  but it in that case the tails are within $\epsilon>0$ of 0 for any $\epsilon$ @postmortes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $||T_n x||^2_{l^2} =  e_{n+1}^2+e_{n+2}^2 \leq ||x||^2_{l^2}$

Since $x \in l^2$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (e_{n+1}^2 + e_{n+2}^2) = 0$ (since tails tend to $0$). Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $||T_n x||^2_{l^2} \leq \varepsilon$.

This means that $\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n x = 0$. But that is, by definition, equal to $Tx$. So for all $x \in l^2$, $Tx=0$. So $T$ is the zero operator.

Comment: Pretty sure the operator had infinite 1's, not just the next two 1s, by the definition

Comment: Oh wait, does your notation imply that $T_n(x)$ is truncating $x$ before the $n$-th term? Then this is wrong, but it still works. Just write $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty e_j^2 = 0$, which is a tail, so it tends to $0$.

Comment: *nod* That's what I did in the answer above

Comment: @Alan I realized this three seconds after posting the answer, let's see if the OP confirms

Answer (score 2):

Every element $x\in l^2$ is such that for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$,   $\lim_{n\to \infty} |x_n|=0$.   Even stronger,  you have the squared sum of the terms going to zero because the tail of any monotone sequence must taper off. Thus,  for each $x$,  $\| T_n x\|=\left( \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (x_k)^2 \right)^{\frac 1 2}\to 0  $ as $n\to \infty$